# Search channels in Sendbird virsion 3.X.X

Tags: javascript, sendbird

I am trying to move SendBird JavaScript SDK v3.0.0  from SendBird JavaScript SDK v2.4.20. But the problem is i am not getting a way to search open channels. in previous version (v2) i used

```
sendbird.getChannelSearch({
            "query": query,
            "successFunc" : function(data) {
                 console.log(data[channels]);
                },
            "errorFunc": function(status, error) {
                console.log(status, error);
            }
 });
```

see https://docs.sendbird.com/v2/javascript#sdk_function_open_chat

But in new version i don't have idea how to do  it.

Does anyone have idea ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest v3 sdk in all major platforms now support "Public Channel Search". Please download the latest and try it!

Thanks!